# How to display table header in every page using FPDF library?

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf, fpdf

just need your help with my code.
My question is how can I get the table header from the previous page and access it on the remaining pages? If I have a large data I want to indicate also the header table in every page. But I don't have an idea how to do it.

Here's the function that build the table:

```
function BuildTable($header,$data) {

            //Colors, line width and bold font
            $this->SetFillColor(255,255,255);
            $this->SetTextColor(0);
            $this->SetDrawColor(0,0,0);
            $this->SetLineWidth(.3);
            $this->SetFont('Arial','',7);

            //Header    
            // make an array for the column widths

            $this->SetFillColor(0,0,0);
            $this->SetTextColor(255);
            $this->SetDrawColor(0,0,0);
            $this->SetLineWidth(.3);
            $this->SetFont('','B');

            $w = array(15,120,30,30);  //CHANGE THIS
            // send the headers to the PDF document

            for($i = 0; $i < count($header); $i++)

                $this->Cell($w[$i],7,$header[$i],1,0,'C',1);
                $this->Ln();

                //Color and font restoration

                $this->SetFillColor(255,255,230);
                $this->SetTextColor(0);
                $this->SetFont('');
                $this->SetTextColor(0);
                $fill = false; // used to alternate row color backgrounds

            //HERE'S THE PART THAT LOOPS THE DATA
            foreach($data as $row){ 

                $this->Cell($w[0],4,$row[0],'LR',0,'C',$fill);
                $this->SetFont('');

                $this->Cell($w[1],4,$row[1],'LR',0,'L',$fill);
                $this->SetFont('');

                $this->Cell($w[2],4,$row[2],'LR',0,'R',$fill);
                $this->SetFont('');

                $this->Cell($w[3],4,$row[3],'LR',0,'R',$fill);
                $this->SetFont('');



                $this->Ln();
                $fill =! $fill;
            }

              $this->Cell(array_sum($w),0,'','T');


              $this->Ln(50);
              $this->Ln(50);

        }
```

Below is the call for PDF class

```
foreach($result->result_array() as $row){

        $data[] = array($row['item_qty'],
                        $row['itemname'],
                        number_format($row['item_price'],2),
                        number_format($row['total'],2),

                 );

    }


    $pdf = new PDF();
    $pdf->AliasNbPages();

    $header = array('QTY','ITEM / DESCRIPTION' , 'UNIT PRICE', 'TOTAL AMOUNT');

    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',8);
    $pdf->SetFillColor(255,0,0);

    $pdf->AddPage('l');

    $pdf->Ln();
    $pdf = new PDF();
```

By the way I have also a header and footer function.
In first row I need to have 39 rows excluding the table header and the second row and also the remaining should 36 rows.

How can I compute that? Where should I need a computation for that?

Please help me guys thanks.

Comment: Can you show us your header function?

Answer (score 0):

According to fpdf tutorial.

```
class PDF extends FPDF
{
// Page header
function Header()
{
    // Logo
    $this->Image('logo.png',10,6,30);
    // Arial bold 15
    $this->SetFont('Arial','B',15);
    // Move to the right
    $this->Cell(80);
    // Title
    $this->Cell(30,10,'Title',1,0,'C');
    // Line break
    $this->Ln(20);
}

// Page footer
function Footer()
{
    // Position at 1.5 cm from bottom
    $this->SetY(-15);
    // Arial italic 8
    $this->SetFont('Arial','I',8);
    // Page number
    $this->Cell(0,10,'Page '.$this->PageNo().'/{nb}',0,0,'C');
}
}

// Instanciation of inherited class
$pdf = new PDF();
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Times','',12);
for($i=1;$i<=40;$i++)
    $pdf->Cell(0,10,'Printing line number '.$i,0,1);
$pdf->Output();
```

[reference](http://www.fpdf.org/en/tutorial/tuto2.htm)